# Is it possible to monitor all network traffic in a Safari Extension?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Since the newer versions of Safari (I'm running version 5.2) seem to have removed the "Activity" viewer from the "Window" menu, I would like to write an extension to have this feature back.  However, in order to do that I think that I will need to be able to see what URLs are being requested in that window/tab.  For Chrome, there is a ["webRequest" API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html) that does this, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for to do this in Safari.  Would someone please tell me if this is possible, and if so, where should I look next?  Thanks in advance.

So far, the most I've been able to get is using an injected start script like the one below:

```
function trackRequests() {
    console.log(event.timeStamp + ": " + event.type, event.url, event);
}
document.addEventListener("beforeload", trackRequests, true);
```

However, this does not provide enough for the features I'll need for this.  For example, if a URL is specified without a protocol e.g. "//example.com/file.txt" that is all this handlers sees; it doesn't know what actual protocol was used or if the request was allowed.

It appears that [some people on the Apple discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4138462?start=0&tstart=0), [MacDailyNews](http://macdailynews.com/2012/08/10/the-top-10-most-missed-features-apple-removed-from-os-x-mountain-lion/), and [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/08/the-10-features-removed-from-mountain-lion-that-we-miss-the-most/) have expressed a desire to have this feature back in Safari as well.  [Here's a link to another discussion on MacRumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1411248) and [another](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=15330042#post15330042).

Answer (score 1):

On windows I would use Fiddler but since you appear to be using a Mac here are some alternatives:

http://alternativeto.net/software/fiddler/?platform=mac

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Http Scoop might be what you are looking for: http://www.tuffcode.com/. You asked for a Safari plugin but this works independently from what browser you use so you can use it in combination with Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Jos. I already use Fiddler and am happy with it for typical debugging & experimentation. However, I'm specifically looking for an easy way to view a list of URLs (particularly protocol & hostname to find SSL-related warnings) that a browser requests for individual pages. Using a proxy is tedious because one needs to flush caches, filter results, etc. Using the new web inspector's network page is not ideal because it takes many clicks. Right now, I can use an older version of Safari and use the "Activity Viewer" but was hoping for a more long-term, built-in solution.